# Using TxD pin and NeoPixel library for RGB LEDs

Tags: esp8266, rgb-led, neopixel

I have no free pin on my ESP-12 but GPIO16 and TxD (GPIO1). I use [Neo Pixel Library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel) and this design:
[image]

- GPIO16 powers it on/off
- TxD uses to handle single-wire-based for LEDs (GPIO1)

It works but it has one issue. I use USB <> TTL converter to program my ESP, it just worked for 1 2 times and after that burned the converter! I'm afraid there's something wrong with my design. Any better idea to use GPIO16 and TxD to do that? I need to power down LEDs when I don't need them to save power.

Comment: I would consider optimising the rest of your design and free up some other pins to use.

Comment: There probably is something electrically wrong, but *what* cannot be determined from the information you posted.  You could disconnect the LED power supply while programming, but that only lessens the chance - whatever damaged components could still damage something else.